# Javascript: "ReferenceError: validGears is not defined", even though it clearly is??? (VSCode, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, methods, static

I'm running a js file on vscode (Node.js), and there's a static variable (array) in my Car class that is clearly defined, but the debugger doesn't see it as defined.

This is my current code for the Car class:

```
class Car {
    constructor(data = {}) {
        this.color = data.color || "blue";
        this.currentSpeed = data.currentSpeed || 0;
        this.topSpeed = data.topSpeed || 25;
        this.currentGear = data.currentGear || "Park";
        this.maxGas = data.maxGas || 10; // Litres
        this.currentGas = data.currentGas || this.maxGas;
    }

    static validGears = ["Park", "Neutral", "Drive"];
    changeGear(newGear) {
        switch (newGear) {
            case this.currentGear:
                console.log("Car is already in " + newGear);
                break;
            case validGears[newGear]:
                this.currentGear = newGear;
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Invalid gear.")
        }
    }
}
```

"validGears" (defined on line 11) is an array of strings representing possible gears the car can be in. Simple enough, right? Well, take a look at the next few lines (this is in the same file):

```
let newCar = new Car({color: "Magenta", currentSpeed: 15});
newCar.changeGear("Drive");
```

I create an instance, and call the changeGear method, yet the error I've aforementioned claims the validGears array doesn't exist (wherever the validGears variable is mentioned inside the changeGear method, it throws an error).

I'm new to JavaScript, so maybe I'm missing something, but this honestly seems like it should be really simple. Am I a buffoon???

Comment: To access a `static` variable you need to use something like `Car.validGears `

Answer (score 1):

You can call static members using class name (*ClassName.staticMemberName*) For ex; `Car.validGears`

Comment: *You can only call static members using class name*, that is not true, you can also use something like `this.constructor.staticMemberName`

Comment: @Titus yes that's right. Let me correct my sentence.